# How to provide an Api for your angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, widget, directive

Until now I've been developing widgets in javascript without AngularJS.
The approach is always the same: the widget provide an API that allow the clients to change him from any part of their application.
The approach has not change but now I need use AngularJS. I have though in the next solution and I would like to know your options:

```
angular.module("app", ["myCustomWidget"])

.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "myCustomWidgetService", function($scope, myCustomWidgetService) {
  $scope.myCustomWidgetService = myCustomWidgetService;
  $scope.changeMyCustomWidget = function() {
    $scope.myCustomWidgetService.message = "This message was written by MainCtrl";
  }
}]);


/**
WIDGET
*/
angular.module("myCustomWidget", [])

.factory("myCustomWidgetService", function() {
  var myCustomWidgetService = {};
  myCustomWidgetService.message = "This is the default message inside the Service";
  return myCustomWidgetService;
})

.directive("myCustomWidgetDirective", [function() {
  return {
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: "$ctrl", // I dont know where it is used but angular fails if it is not present -> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/noident
    controller: "myCustomWidgetCtrl",
    scope: {},
    template: '<button ng-click="changeMyCustomWidget()" type="button" name="button">Click to change from directive</button><p>{{myCustomWidgetService.message}}</p>'
  }
}])

.controller("myCustomWidgetCtrl", ["$scope", "myCustomWidgetService", function($scope, myCustomWidgetService) {
  $scope.myCustomWidgetService = myCustomWidgetService; //Use the Service as a part of the scope
  $scope.changeMyCustomWidget = function() {
    $scope.myCustomWidgetService.message = "This message was written by myCustomWidgetCtrl";
  }
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/L58WpCkGyYionGfoeewd

What do you think? it is a good idea use a Service as a part of the directive controller?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to inject services into controllers. Their entire purpose in life is to handle data for controllers, which are the middle managers of most any MVC app.

Your use case is one of the most common; you're having your controller walk up to your service and go, "Hey, please show this message for me." Then later another controller walks up and asks the service to show a different message. And so on and so forth.

You might also have a controller walk up to a service -- possibly wearing a trench coat and fedora -- and, with a hoarse whisper, go "Hey, please hold this data for me. I've got a friend coming by to pick it up. No, it's all cool and on the level." And the service, which has had this happen a tryingly vast number of times in its life, knows exactly the protocol for doing it. Put the data on this shelf; flip on this light; resist the urge to `alert(cops)`. Later, another controller -- also wearing a trench coat and fedora, but this time it's *beige* instead of *black* -- walks up, takes the data, nods, then disappears into the night.

In both cases, the service knows nothing about how or why it's doing anything; that's the controller's job. Similarly, the controller doesn't know how or why anything is done once it hands off its task; it just expects things to work.

Hopefully that helps.